# What makes Lustre faster and more scalable than NFS?

Tags: filesystems, nfs, cluster, hpc, lustre

I have read in various places (e.g. [here](http://wiki.lustre.org/index.php/NFS_vs._Lustre) and [here](http://wiki.whamcloud.com/display/PUB/Why+Use+Lustre)) that NFS' I/O performance does **not** scale, while Lustre's does, and that Lustre can deliver better I/O rates in general.

There seem to be various architectural differences between the two, but I can't identify what exactly gives Lustre the bump in speed or scalability. I guess my question is somewhat conceptual, but what is the **key** difference with respect to NFS, or feature, that allows Lustre to scale and deliver faster I/O rates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NFS is from 1 client to 1 server, so the overall performance is limited by the performance of that 1 server. Adding more servers does not help.

Lustre splits the data, the data gets requested from 1 server, but can be sent from one or more other servers. So adding more servers does help (which is why "Lustre scales").
This is an important bit from your first link:

> Lustre IO performance *does* scale. It uses a 3rd-party transfer. Requests are made to the metadata server and IO moves directly between the affected storage component(s) and the client.